# GEPlugin does not load KML files on VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, google-earth-plugin

I have developed an app using the GEPlugin located at **https://code.google.com/p/winforms-geplugin-control-library/**.

I use the GEWebBrowser and the GETreeView, and both works nicely.

I only load local kml files on the controls, so the way to do this, is to copy the "KML_Samples.kml" file into the webroot directory, and call the function as follows:

```
GeWebBrowser.FetchKml(http://localhost:8080/KML_Samples.kml)
```

Each time I call this method, the event GeWebBrowser_KmlLoaded is launched in the correct way.

However, I have checked lately that this works fine for the two or three first kml files loaded. After this two or three files, when I try to load a new kml file, I can see that the  the KML_Samples.kml file has been updated, but the GeWebBrowser_KmlLoaded event IS NOT LAUNCHED!

I have tried to execute the app step by step setting a breakpoint on the line

```
GeWebBrowser.FetchKml(http://localhost:8080/KML_Samples.kml)
```

and in this case, I can load the kml files!!.

I have tried to execute some code after this line in order to execute all the pending events, with the following line:

```
Application.DoEvents()
```

However, this has not the expected result, and the trouble remains: I'm only able to load the two or three first kml files.

I wonder if something is missing by my side using this control, but I have not found anything on the documentation that could help me.

If anyone could help me with this issue, I would be very thankful .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my own question.

I have detected the GEControl does not works fine with the built-in server. I can load local kml files by sopying them at webroot\KML_Samples.kml, but this only works for the first two or three files to be loaded.
For the following kml files, it doesn't work. I suppose there is some mistake inside the control, so I'm going to develop all the code that load the kml file into a TreeView (I'll try to use the KmlTreeView), and load all the separated points of each kml file into the plugin.